# dropwizard: incorrect json resulting from group of items

Tags: json, dropwizard

I am using Dropwizard to deliver a RESTful service. The JSON I EXPECT looks like this:

```
{"featuredMerchants":
    {"featuredMerchant":[
        {"browseId":"v1_0_0_1112",
            "merchantId":3902,
            "priority":1,
            "sourceId":"15"},
        ...,
        {"browseId":"v1_0_0_1112",
            "merchantId":456,
            "priority":4,
            "sourceId":"15"}]}}
```

But the JSON I am GETTING is this:

```
{"featuredMerchant":[
    {"browseId":"v1_0_0_1112",
        "merchantId":3902,
        "priority":1,
        "sourceId":"15"},
    ...,
    {"browseId":"v1_0_0_1112",
        "merchantId":456,
        "priority":4,
        "sourceId":"15"}]}
```

I have two classes. I have an `ApiFeaturedMerchantGroup` class that contains a list of `ApiFeaturedMerchant`s.

```
@JsonRootName("featuredMerchants")
public class ApiFeaturedMerchantGroup {
    private List<ApiFeaturedMerchant> apiFeaturedMerchants;

    public ApiFeaturedMerchantGroup() {
    }

    @JsonProperty("featuredMerchant")
    public List<ApiFeaturedMerchant> getApiFeaturedMerchants() { return apiFeaturedMerchants; } 
    public void setApiFeaturedMerchants(List<ApiFeaturedMerchant> apiFeaturedMerchants) { this.apiFeaturedMerchants = apiFeaturedMerchants; }
}

@JsonRootName("featuredMerchant")
public class ApiFeaturedMerchant {

    private String browseId;
    private int merchantId;
    private Integer priority;
    private String sourceId;

    public ApiFeaturedMerchant() {
    }

    public String getBrowseId() { return browseId; }
    public void setBrowseId(String browseId) { this.browseId = browseId; }

    public int getMerchantId() { return merchantId; } 
    public void setMerchantId(int merchantId) { this.merchantId = merchantId; }

    public Integer getPriority() { return priority; } 
    public void setPriority(Integer priority) { this.priority = priority; }

    public String getSourceId() { return sourceId; } 
    public void setSourceId(String sourceId) { this.sourceId = sourceId; }
}
```

How do I get the extra level into my JSON, the "featuredMerchants" group that contains the individual "featuredMerchant" items? Do I have the wrong annotations, or am I missing one/some?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a setting on ObjectMapperFactory:

```
ObjectMapperFactory objectMapperFactory = new ObjectMapperFactory();
objectMapperFactory.enable(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
objectMapper = objectMapperFactory.build();
```